# Multi Stores not working

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, store-view

On my website www.antistaticesd.com, I want to make a new store.

There are two root categories:

1. Default Category for default store on www.antistaticesd.com
2. Business Store  for businesses to purchase business products. I have set up a directory for this www.antistaticesd.com/business

After creating the "business store" root category and "business_store_view" store view, I did the following:

Went to System >> Configuration
Selected "business_store_view" from Current Configuration scope to switch to business store configuration.
Went to "Web" from left panel.
Unchecked the "Use Website [STORE VIEW]"
Changed the Secure and Unsecure base URLs to "www.antistaticesd.com/business".

Also added the following lines to my .htaccess file( that is in the root installation of magento):

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.antistaticesd\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=default
SetEnvIf Host www\.antistaticesd\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^antistaticesd\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=default
SetEnvIf Host ^antistaticesd\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

SetEnvIf Host www\.antistaticesd\.com/business MAGE_RUN_CODE=business_store_view
SetEnvIf Host www\.antistaticesd\.com/business MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
SetEnvIf Host ^antistaticesd\.com/business MAGE_RUN_CODE=business_store_view
SetEnvIf Host ^antistaticesd\.com/business MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
```

Still, I see nothing but an error screen on reindexing and refreshing.
Please, Please help!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this works when the second store is a subfolder of the main store.
But you can just create the folder `business` inside the root directory, copy `index.php` and `.htaccess` files from the root to the new folder.
Then edit `index.php` and replace

```
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
```

with

```
$mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';
```

and

```
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

with

```
Mage::run('business_store_view', 'store');
```

Comment: For creating third website is it the same procedure? eg: 1) Main_website : $mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';  2) Second_website: $mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php'; 3) Third_website: ??? thanks @Marius♦

Comment: Yes.same procedre. Just use the website code i stead of store ie view code

Comment: Finally done after that may I know why I am getting the error " Refused to apply js, mime type erroe". Any possibility of error. Thanks